# Clojure set/project does not maintain order. what to do?

Tags: clojure

set/project in Clojure does not maintain order as can be seen with:

```
(project (map #(hash-map :number % :square (* % %)) (range 100)) #{:square})
```

is there an idiomatic way to use it while maintaining order or would I have to explicitly add the ordinals and sort them afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of `clojure.set/project`:

```
(defn project
  "Returns a rel of the elements of xrel with only the keys in ks"
  {:added "1.0"}
  [xrel ks]
    (set (map #(select-keys % ks) xrel)))
```

You need to implement your own `project` without converting result into `set`

```
(defn my-project [xrel ks]
  (map #(select-keys % ks) xrel))
```

Test:

```
(my-project (map #(hash-map :number % :square %) 
                 (range 100)) 
            #{:square})
=> ({:square 0}
    {:square 1}
    {:square 2}
    {:square 3}
    ...
    {:square 99})
```

**Update**. Another version:

```
(defn my-project2 [xrel ks] 
  (map (fn [m] (into {} (filter #(ks (key %)) m)))
       xrel))
```

Comment: .. which begs the question: what's the benefit of using set in the library? It would seem counter-intuitive to me that the result of the projection may have a different count due to same keys being represented only once.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus I had not seen this function until you asked. I can only assume that it's because `project` is a part of `clojure.set` which designed to work with sets (?).

Comment: `clojure.set` is intended as an light weight implementation  relational algebra working with sets of maps representing relations. See [this blog post](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2010/08/21/some-relational-algebra-with-datatypes-in-clojure-12) for an overview.  `project` is intended for use in concert with `join`, `select` etc.